# How do I check if a specific fix in the Linux kernel has been included in a longterm kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, backports

I'm specifically wondering if the patch for [this bug](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93581) has been included in the 4.1 longterm tree, or if it hasn't I'd like to know how best to keep tabs on when/if it does get included. The relevant git commit is [ca369d51b3e1649be4a72addd6d6a168cfb3f537](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable/+/ca369d51b3e1649be4a72addd6d6a168cfb3f537).

Though I'm currently interested in this fix specifically, the general question of how to best find out if a specific change has been included in a previous (but still supported) kernel is I think interesting and useful. Since I don't have a good overview of how linux kernel development and documentation is handled it's difficult to guess how best to go about this.

Comment: You could also state your preference (if any) for either downloading (part of) the kernel git repository vs figuring it out via the web interface.

Comment: @Faheem Mitha Either one would be fine by me.

Comment: Ok. Well, if you have the bandwidth and the disk space, cloning the git repos would probably be more efficient than messing with html log pages.

Answer (score 1):

Check in https://kernel.org/ for the changelog of the kernel of interest.  You can search for the commit id.  You can mangle also the url of the changelog to check the previous version of the same LTS.

Comment: Thanks. If the commit ID can be expected to show up in the changelog that's a decent way to check. What if there are many changelogs to go through, is there a easier way to get a complete list other than going to each changelog manually (except scripting that process myself)?

Comment: You have google, e.g. with the addition of <code>site:kernel.org</code>.  Note, it seems that the commit got an other id: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/jejb/scsi-for-next.changelog (3rd commit from the bottom)